# Convert byte array to float array in Python 3

Tags: python, binary, decode

I am sending 1.0 and 2.0 as binary from C program to STDOUT:

```
    float array[2] = { 1.0, 2.0 };
    fwrite(&array[0], sizeof(array[0]), sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]), stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
```

Python program reads STDOUT as:

```
b'\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@'
```

When I try to convert this back to float, this works:

```
struct.unpack('<f', array[0:4]) # 1.0
struct.unpack('<f', array[4:8]) # 2.0
```

However, if I try to decode the whole array at once, it fails:

```
struct.unpack('<f', array)
```

with the following message:

```
error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

Is it possible to decode the whole array at once, or I should decode in a loop each float separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using struct

Base on the [struct module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) the `struct.unpack()` function must have defined exact format for unpacking multiple values at once. So if you need to use `struct` module, then you either have to define the format using format as `'<ff'` or iterate over the array using [struct.iter_unpack(format, buffer)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.iter_unpack).

#### Using array

Another option is to use [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module, which allows you to decode the binary data at once. You can change endianness using [array.byteswap()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.byteswap) method. The only restriction is that the whole array must have same type.

```py
import array

arr = array.array('f', b'\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@')

arr.tolist()
# [1.0, 2.0]

# change endianness
arr.byteswap()

arr.tolist()
# [4.600602988224807e-41, 8.96831017167883e-44]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's strcut provide some essential tooling, but is a bit clumsy to work with.
In particular, for this, it'd have to yield all your floats as a tuple of Python floats (which are "enormous" objetcs with 10s of bytes each), and then insert then into an array.

Fortunatelly, Python's `array.array` class itself can fill in its values given a bytes object, or even read then directly from a file.

```py
import array

data = b'\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@'
arr = array.array('f')
arr.frombytes(data)
print(arr)
```

Yields:

```
array('f', [1.0, 2.0])
```

(to read directly from a file, use the `fromfile` method)